# Fancybox2: horizontal transitions instead of vertical - how?

Tags: fancybox

In the [examples page](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) when you search (`CTRL+F`) for `image gallery` and click the first image, there's this image gallery which you can browse with next/prev arrows. The animation between them is vertical -- the images fly vertically. How does one set them to fly horizontally?

In the help I found:

> openMethod / closeMethod / nextMethod / prevMethod
>
> Method from $.fancybox.transitions() that handles transition (you can
>   add custom effects there)

But I don't know where to go from here.

Also, [this seems to be slightly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569211/fancybox-2-0-next-and-previous-method-for-gallery-mode).

Comment: you may need to create your own custom transitions. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8374724/1055987

Comment: Did you ever find a horizontal transition method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom transitions from here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xZBBS/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        }
    });
```

try this i am sure this will help